# Crystal Report->subreport->C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

I want to know if is there any way to disable the new tab when I click on the subreport?
Confused? OK.. when we click on subreport, the report for that report comes out like when you click on abc.rpt where abc.rpt is a subreport. In a new tab, abc.rpt itself comes out.
Any way to disable that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer for that is in another question named "2 formats in 1 crystal report".

Answer (score 0):

it is too simple , in the crystalReportViewer1 (the viewer) properties make EnableDrillDown in false